# Check box issue in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with check box in the each card in the view. I want to unchek all the other checkboxes when i clicks on a particular check box in the view(Condition can be like card contains an odd one etc). How can i do that? My adapter code is below.

```
public class PlatformAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatformAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Batch> batches;
ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses;
boolean isInstituteStudent;

public void setBatches(ArrayList<Batch> batches) {
    this.batches = batches;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setCourses(ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ArrayList<CourseSlug> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public ArrayList<Batch> getBatches() {
    return batches;
}

public void setInstituteStudent(boolean instituteStudent) {
    isInstituteStudent = instituteStudent;
}

public boolean isInstituteStudent() {
    return isInstituteStudent;
}

public PlatformAdapter() {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    batches = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (isInstituteStudent) {
        Batch batch = batches.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(batch.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(batch.isPreselect());
    } else {
        final CourseSlug course = courses.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(course.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(course.isPreselect());


    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return isInstituteStudent ? batches.size() : courses.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                int index = getLayoutPosition();
                if(isInstituteStudent) {
                    Batch batch = batches.get(index);
                    batch.setPreselect(b);
                } else {
                    CourseSlug course = courses.get(index);
                    course.setPreselect(b);



                        }
                    }


        });

    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}
}
```

In my Courseslug class, there is a param called isTrue(); if ,courseSlug.isTrue()==true; then which card's check box is satisfying my condition, it gets checked and other unchecked/checked boxes gets unchecked. This is what i want done.

```
public class CourseSlug {
String name;
String slug;
boolean preselect;
boolean istrue;

public boolean isTrue() {
    return istrue;
}

public void setisTrue(boolean isTrue) {
    this.isTrue = istrue;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public boolean isPreselect() {
    return preselect;
}

public void setPreselect(boolean preselect) {
    this.preselect = preselect;
}}
```

Comment: please share your adapter code

Comment: yes i did.please check it now @PhanVanLinh

Comment: You want to check checkbox on that specific list item or of all list items in that activity ?

Comment: yes i want. If that specific item is belong to a condition(That i can implement), then all Oother checked items should be unchecked and current item is checked. @NoumanGhaffar

Comment: For example, if recycle view have 7 items. User check the checkbox of  1st item rest of the six check boxes must be changed to unchecked ?

Comment: yes that is what i want.for more specific, i have reedited my question please check again. @NoumanGhaffar

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Since you've mentioned that it's enough to provide a solution that supports `CourseSlug` class, I've deleted `Batch` class for now and came up with a solution for your needs. Check below:

**Example.java**

```
package com.rencsaridogan.stackoverflow;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<CourseSlug> courseSlugs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      courseSlugs.add(new CourseSlug());
    }

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    final PlatformAdapter platformAdapter = new PlatformAdapter();
    platformAdapter.setCourses(courseSlugs);
    PlatformAdapter.Listener listener = new PlatformAdapter.Listener() {
      @Override public void onCheckedChanged(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < courseSlugs.size(); i++){
          if (i != position){
            Log.i("Checked",i + " false" + " (Other)");
            courseSlugs.get(i).setPreselect(false);
          }
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            if (!recyclerView.isComputingLayout()) {
              platformAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    platformAdapter.setListener(listener);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(platformAdapter);
  }
}
```

**PlatformAdapter.java**

```
package com.rencsaridogan.stackoverflow;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by rencsaridogan on 16/02/2017.
 */

public class PlatformAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatformAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses;
  Listener listener;

  public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  public void setCourses(ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public ArrayList<CourseSlug> getCourses() {
    return courses;
  }

  public PlatformAdapter() {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CourseSlug course = courses.get(position);
    holder.enrolment.setText(course.getName());
    holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(course.isPreselect());
    holder.selectEnrollment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("Checked", holder.getAdapterPosition() + " " + holder.selectEnrollment.isChecked());
        course.setPreselect(holder.selectEnrollment.isChecked());
        if (holder.selectEnrollment.isChecked() && listener != null) {
          listener.onCheckedChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override public int getItemCount() {
    return courses.size();
  }

  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
      selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);
    }
  }

  @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
  }

  public interface Listener {
    void onCheckedChanged(int position);
  }
}
```

**CourseSlug.java**

```
package com.rencsaridogan.stackoverflow;

/**
 * Created by rencsaridogan on 16/02/2017.
 */

public class CourseSlug {
  String name;
  String slug;
  boolean preselect;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
  }

  public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
  }

  public boolean isPreselect() {
    return preselect;
  }

  public void setPreselect(boolean preselect) {
    this.preselect = preselect;
  }
}
```

You don't need another boolean in `CourseSlug` since you have `preselect` variable. I've checked this in a real environment on a device (LG Nexus 5) and I can safely say that it works.

Comment: Do use this approach if you have lets say 15 items your app will became slow on this screen . I.e bad user experience.

Comment: notifySetDataChanged(); can be used outside the for statement, you are right @NoumanGhaffar. I've changed the solution of myself a bit to your suggestion. However, if the architecture was designed by me I would do a complete different approach, but to modify the given code this seems to be a good solution.

Comment: This method crashes my app. See in my Courseslug class, there is a param called isTrue(); if ,courseSlug.isTrue()==true; then which card's check box is satisfying my condition, it gets checked and other unchecked/checked boxes gets checked. This is what i want done.

Comment: Can you share the Class codes of this Course and Batch as well so I can provide you a complete new design and solution? @AtHulAntony

Comment: @rencsaridogan please check my question again. I have made it more specific.

Comment: @AtHulAntony what about Batch class, do you have same thing there as well? It would be easier if you can paste Class codes so I can run my code and give back the working version.

Comment: batch is not at all required.. Do it for Class. If it is working in Class.class, then i can implement it there. I will paste it in my code. Just a second. please check it @rencsaridogan

Comment: @AtHulAntony I've prepared you the working example, check my updated answer. You can do the same thing for your Batch class.

Answer (score 0):

Add below method to your adapter and call it when selectAll checkbox pressed.

```
public void unselectAll(int checkedIndex){
        for(int i=0; i<courses.size(); i++){
            if(i == checkedIndex){
                courses.get(i).setPreselect(true);
                continue;
            }
            courses.get(i).setPreselect(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Use:

```
yourCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                unselectAll(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please read my question again. I have made it more clear. This is not i want.

Comment: This works partially. When i click on the odd card other cards check boxes gets unchecked. But i cannot uncheck the odd card or if i checks other cards after checking odd card, odd card not getting unchecked automatically. Please update code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution. 
Create an `interface` In your `adapter`

```
public interface OnCheckChangedListener {
    void onItemCheckedChange(yourList list , Index indexOfCheckedItem);
}
```

Also create it's instance in adapter as well

```
 OnCheckChangedListiner listener;
```

Now pass this `interface` in the `constructor` of your `recyleview`. Or you can create its setter in your `adapter`.

```
public void setListiner (OnCheckChangedListiner listener ){
this.listener = listener;
}
```

Now `implement` this `listener` in your `activity` or `fragment` and after creating the `instance` of your `adapter` you can set this `listener` like this

```
 platformAdapter.setListener(YourFragmentName.this);
```

Now in your `adapter` `onCheckChanged` method do this

```
if (listener !=null ) {
listener.onItemCheckedChange(yourList list , Index indexOfCheckedItem);
}
```

Since you have `implemented` this `listener` in your `fragment` or `activity`, You got the index of checked item and the whole list ( The list is passed because you might implemented scroll to load or deleted functionality which might change the original list in fragment ). `Loop` through the whole list and change the data of currentChecked item as well and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`.
By doing this way you can also prevent the bad user experience. You can also re-create the new instance of your `adapter` if needed.

Comment: What is yourlist here According to my code in the question

Comment: platformAdapter.setListener(YourFragmentName.this); this line shows one error. Please give a fix.

Comment: It should be your fragment class name.

Comment: and your list is the list in which u want to change the data.

Comment: I am using activity named sample. So how can i add my activity?